# Hiding a DIV on return of if/else statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to hide this div ID `#signup` within this code I'm working in and can't seem to get it work with what I've been doing. Any good way of hiding this div ID by fading out and in return fading in the new div `#test`? Here's what I got!

HTML (index)

```
     <form id="signup" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
      <fieldset>

          <label for="email" id="address-label">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
          <input type="image" src="i/join.jpg" name="submit" value="Join" class="btn" alt="Join" />

      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div id="response">
        <? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
        <div id="test">test</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#test {display: none;}
```

JS/PHP (inc/store-address.php)

```
<?php
function storeAddress(){

    if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
        // It worked!
    ( "#signup" ).hide( "slow" );   
    ( "#test" ).show( "slow" );
    }

    else {
        // An error ocurred, return error message   
        return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
    }

}

// If being called via ajax, autorun the function
if($_GET['ajax']){ echo storeAddress(); }
?>
```

Comment: Are you seriously trying to mix PHP and javascript in the same function? PHP executes on the server BEFORE the page is served to the browser.  Javascript executes in the client AFTER the page has been received by the browser.  The two must be completely separate.

Comment: @jfriend00 Apparently, I wasn't sure if/what works within the same function. I apologize for not having enough knowledge to know I couldn't do so. Anyways, thanks for replying. I really appreciate your time!!

Comment: @DoPeT Are the transition effects important to you, this would be trivial in plain php. Also simple with ajax but probably beyond your current understanding

Comment: @user574632 They are definitely are wanted, but I could suffice without it!

Comment: @DoPeT ok, i will write an answer

Comment: @DoPeT before i write an answer, how do you initialize $api variable? The current code does not show

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are trying to mix php and Javascript in one function, but this will not work. Php runs serverside before the webpage has been sent to the client, and Javascript runs only on the client and only after the page has been sent.

You will need to do this in JavaScript most likely, Jquery is a light library that is highly reccomended for a task like this.

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) is a link where the code below was harvested from.

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
  $("p").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use php to conditionally output js to the browser - not the most elegant but it will work; The comments about server / client side are important and you do have to be very mindful of single / double quotes.

```
<?php
function storeAddress(){

    if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
        // It worked!

     echo '<script>';
     echo '$( "#signup" ).hide( "slow" );';   
     echo '$( "#test" ).show( "slow" );';   
     echo '</script>';

    }

    else {
        // An error ocurred, return error message   
        return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
    }

}

// If being called via ajax, autorun the function
if($_GET['ajax']){ echo storeAddress(); }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! It worked and hid the signup form and now it seems the #test won't show.. I wonder if it's the display: hidden that I'm targeting for #test.

Comment: shouldnt it be display:none ?

Comment: @DoPeT The immediate problem is that the js is executed before test div exists, just moving it before the php include or wrapping js in $(function(){}); would 'fix' that, the real problem is a confusing illogical php/js bodge job.